# Passing arguments by running a python script to a jar

Tags: java, python, command-line-arguments

I have a simple Java app that does an addition by passing 2 arguments when running it. Here is the code:

```
package test_python;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Test_python {

public int addition(int first, int second) {
return first + second;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
Test_python a = new Test_python();
System.out.println(a.addition(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1])));

 

}

}
```

And I have a python script :

```
import subprocess
import sys


first_arg = subprocess.check_output([sys.argv])
second_arg = subprocess.check_output([sys.argv])
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'test_python.jar ',first_arg,second_arg])
```

I would like to pass two arguments like 2 and 3 to the python script and the to send the arguments to the jar and return the response. I get this error when I try:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Certificat python\start-stop.py", line 5, in <module>
first_arg = subprocess.check_output([sys.argv])
File "C:\Users\40723\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 
424, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "C:\Users\40723\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 
505, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "C:\Users\40723\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 
951, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\40723\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 
1360, in _execute_child
args = list2cmdline(args)
File "C:\Users\40723\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 
565, in list2cmdline
for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
File "C:\Users\40723\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 822, in 
fsdecode
filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Can you please give me a solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the command on how the python script was invoked? Is it just `python script.py 2 3`? Or `./script.py 2 3`? Or something else?

Comment: python script.py 2 3

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is because `sys.argv` is already a list e.g. `["script.py", "2", "3"]` and you are wrapping it in another list thus making it `[["script.py", "2", "3"]]`.

```
first_arg = subprocess.check_output([sys.argv])
```

Removing the outer list-wrapper and also removing the first item which is the script itself would remove the error.

```
first_arg = subprocess.check_output(sys.argv[1:])
```

But I doubt that is what you need, because [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) runs the command, it doesn't get the arguments as what you are trying to do.

```
$ python script.py cat script.py  # <cat> is a linux command that prints the file
b'#!/usr/bin/env python\n\nimport subprocess\nimport sys\n\n\nresult = subprocess.check_output(sys.argv[1:])\nprint(result)\n'
```

If what you want is to just get the values of the first and second argument e.g. `2` and `3` if invoked as `python script.py 2 3`, you can just do:

```
first_arg = sys.argv[1]
second_arg = sys.argv[2]
```